# Is win32/keygen dangerous?

Tags: virus, anti-virus

When we download some of illegal software an antivirus often warned about win32/keygen

From [this link](http://www.microsoft.com/security/portal/Threat/Encyclopedia/Entry.aspx?name=HackTool%3AWin32%2FKeygen) I see Kaspersky said not-a-virus:Keygen.

Is win32/keygen dangerous?

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding you correctly, but if an antivirus warned you about it, what makes you think it's not dangerous? (Pro tip: Don't download illegal software if you're worried about viruses)

Comment: @slhck Many of illegal software ofen have only this virus (win32/keygen).It made ​​me think an antivirus not encourage illegal software. (Sorry if my language not clear,I'm not good at english.)

Answer (score 4):

Your antivirus software is alerting you to the presence of a key generator, not to discourage piracy, but to warn you that the software you're using might not be legitimate and to warn you of the general risks of using illegitimate software. The warning usually does not indicate the antivirus has detected actual malware, aside from the keygen itself, if you would classify it as such.

Comment: Most keygens use methods(functions) that are intrusive by nature and are flagged by antivirus software. Usually it's a fake-positive, depending on where you get it.